# Geographically Instantiated model should face geographical head north

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, geolocation

I am working on a android application in which i will place 3d objects based in geographical location. This is working good. The problem is with rotation, object is facing the direction the device is facing. I want the instantiated gameobject to face geographical North direction. How can i do it?
I have tried

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0);
```

It is not working correctly, showing wrong direction. Is there any other way gameobjects should face geographical north.

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you checked that `Input.compass.enabled` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you'll have to actively enable the compass using [`Compass.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-enabled.html) like

```
private void Awake ()
{
    Input.compass.enabled = true;
}
```

otherwise you always get the last retrieved value which by default would be `0` which makes your object be spawned facing into positive `Z` direction of the Unity world.